# How to refresh values in laravel models where enums are replaced with values?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I came across a weird issue while writing tests in laravel using factories. So this is a test I wrote:

```
/**
 @test
 */
public function document_belongs_to_a_patent()
{
    $patent = factory(Patent::class)->create();

    $document = factory(Document::class)->create([
        'documentable_id' => $patent->id,
        'documentable_type' => 'patent'
    ]);

    $this->assertArraySubset($patent->toArray(), $document->documentable->toArray());
}
```

So this should work, right because both should return the same thing and `patent` array should be equal or a subset of `documentable` array. But it was failing when I realised that there is an enum field in `Patent` model to which I am passing the value `1` but it was converted to the enum equivalent value in the database and when I tried `document->documentable->toArray()` it came back with the enum value rather than `1` which got me thinking how can make the model factory return the actual enum value and not the index number.

Top of the head I just fetched the patent just after creating it via the factory like so:

`$patent = Patent::find($patent->id);`

And it works well but it seems inconsistent. Is there a way to refresh models. I know we can refresh relationships of models but is there a way to do for the models themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're strictly needing the change for API, you can do something cheeky with mutators like this.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-serialization

Add this property. It tells Laravel that *for special outputs only*, it needs to append a non-database property.

```
protected $appends = ['documentable_type_name'];
```

Then you need some ways of knowing the language for the enum. You need an array, a `@lang` definition, etc. Here's a protected property solution that I am quite fond of in simple situations.

```
protected static $documentable_types = [ 'divorce', 'patent' ];
```

And then create this mutator on your Documentable model.

```
public function getDocumentableTypeName()
{
    if ($this->documentable_type)
    {
        return static::$documentable_types[ $this->documentable_type ];
    }

    return null;
}
```

This changes your JSON output to look like this:

```
{
    docuemntable_id        : 555,
    documentable_type      : 1,
    documentable_type_name : 'patent'
}
```

You can also hide the `document_type` field by adding this.

```
protected $hidden  = ['documentable_type'];
```

And Laravel magic takes care of the rest. Hope that helps.

Comment: Okay you got confused and that is understandable. The `document_type` field in patent is causing my issue not the `documentable_type` in document. The patent table also contains a field called the `document_type` which is used for something different. That field is enum.

Comment: Probably shouldn't try to answer questions at 2am. I see what you're asking now and it's a lot simpler than what I answered. Do you want `$this->fresh()`? https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fresh